# How to listen to port 80 by using Java Socket

Tags: java, sockets, http, tcp

I have a server whose port 80 is for occupied by HTTP transactions. I wanted to see the traffic in that port and I tried to use a socket program to listen to that port.

```
public Server(int serverPort) throws IOException {  
    super(serverPort);  
    try {  
        while (true) {  
            Socket socket = accept();  
            new ServerThread(socket);  
        }  
    } catch (IOException e) {  
        e.printStackTrace();  
    } finally {  
        close();
    }  
}  

// inner-class ServerThread  
class ServerThread extends Thread {  
    private Socket socket;  
    private BufferedReader in;  
    private PrintWriter out;  

    // Ready to conversation  
    public ServerThread(Socket s) throws IOException {  
        this.socket = s;  
        in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket  
                .getInputStream(), "UTF-8"));  
        out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);  
        start();  
    }  

    // Execute conversation  
    public void run() {  
        try {  

            // Communicate with client until "bye " received.  
            while (true) {  
                String line = in.readLine();  
                if (line == null || "".equals(line.trim())) {
                    break;  
                }  
                System.out.println("Received   message: " + line);  
                out.println(line);  
                out.flush();  
            }  

            out.close();  
            in.close();  
            socket.close();  

        } catch (IOException e) {  
            e.printStackTrace();  
        }  
    }  

}  

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {  
    new Server(80);  
}
```

However, when I run that java application, it showed a BindException: Address already in use.

So what should I do to my code and make it listen to port 80, or are there any other ways to listen to that port in Java?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly you are trying to sniff the packets that are being passed to your server. If that is the case there are some answers in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/590510/java-tcp-socket-sniffing) post.

Comment: Of course I can use Wireshark, but I need to use a standalone java program to automatically show the result.

Comment: There are other comments there, some simple google search lead me to this http://jpcap.sourceforge.net/
But as you can see in the post there they have recommended other libraries.

Comment: Thank you and I finally switched to Pcap4j.

Answer (score 0):

What Server are you running it on?

it all depends on the type of server you're working on. Tomcat for example has the type of port it's running off of in the Server.xml file.

Comment: I have Jetty server running on the 8080 port, btw I do not wish to change the Server.xml file since my socket program is a standalone program and I don't want to make any change to other program run on Jetty.

Answer (score 0):

In Windows you can run your program by administrator. In Linux using root user.